# Store Bit field Boolean Indicator in 1 or 2 columns in the database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have the need for the following `bit` fields/columns in the database:

`IsInbound`
`IsOutbound`

Now, if `IsInbound` is `false (0)`, than the inverse is exactly true which means `IsOutbound` is `true (1)`.

I can obviously create only a single column in my table in the database with either title, and be able to extract the information required based on `true/false` conditions.

However which is the *correct* way to design this? Do I just arbitrarily pick one of the fields and know the opposite value indicates `true/false` or should I be explicit and have *both* fields defined on the table? I've done it both ways over the years and was curious what is the correct design pattern for creating these fields?

Comment: In a nutshell, if something can be _inferred_, it shouldn't be stored.

Comment: Good tip - that's the information I was looking to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to design for this is not to think about space first.

Instead, think about the values.  The way you have described the values, only two combinations are possible:

```
IsInbound      IsOutbound
    1              0
    0              1
```

Both cannot be `0`.  Both cannot be `1`.  In other words, you shouldn't be storing them in two different columns.  If you do, you will need to add a constraint to the table to ensure that the values are different.  Yuck!

If you want both variables, then stored `IsInbound` and add a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add IsOutbound as (IsInbound = 0);
```

Comment: This was the kind of solid reasoning I was seeking. So just pick either field as the column name arbitrarily since it will not matter, or is there any thought process to this too?

Comment: @atconway . . . No thought process on which to store.  If you use the computed column, then either can be used in queries (in case one seems more appropriate in a particular context).

Answer (score 1):

Having one column will require less space overall, even if it is just a simple bit field.  Queries would also be simpler since you only have to check one field instead of two.

Comment: So just pick either field as the column name arbitrarily since it will not matter?